# Ternary operator changing "true" to literal true

Tags: krl

I'm trying to assign a string literal to a variable using a ternary operator with the following code in the `pre` block:

```
texta = "approve";
textd = "deny";
aAction = texta eq "approve" => "true" | "false";
dAction = textd eq "approve" => "true" | "false";
```

However, this is what comes across in the JavaScript:

```
var texta = 'approve';
var textd = 'deny';
var aAction = true;
var dAction = false;
```

Notice that `aAction` and `dAction` should be strings, but they are actually boolean literals.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Is there more to the rule?  This is a bug that I will have to trace to find out where it is getting expressed as a boolean

Comment: A single rule. Here's the whole ruleset: http://pastie.org/1761173

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to force it back into a string is with a beesting:

```
aActionStr = "#{aAction}";
dActionStr = "#{dAction}";
```

Doesn't answer the question as to why this happens, but it's a hack that will work in this case.